# Problem with mysql workbench and xampp server

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a project with mysql. For the past two days I had been using XAMPP server for the mysql server and mysql workbench to use it and it has been working perfectly. Today after having to restart my pc for a windows update, when I turned on the XAMPP mysql server and tried going to my connection in mysql workbench, mysql workbench is giving me an error

```
Could not connect; Server may not be running         Message: Lost connection to mysql server at 'waiting for initial communication packet'. system error 10060
```

I have tried multiple solutions; Changing the port of the mysql server. Using a different username and password, the root username. And have tried restarting my computer multiple times to fix the problem. If any more information is needed to find the problem I will update this question to provide more information.

**UPDATE 1:**

I left my laptop running and when I returned the workbench had connected successfully. I believe the problem comes from restarting the pc as the day after I posted this question I restarted my pc to fix a problem and I am currently having the same situation.

Comment: Is the server actually running?

Comment: Yes it is running on port 3306 the default port, and I tried changing to a different port if that was part of the problem but it did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the Windows Firewall or the Antivirus.
If the server is running all the time and the service not stop, the port is blocked.
Check if the default port is Listening:
C:\Windows\System32>netstat -an |find "3306"

Or you can use the Microsoft Tool PortQry.exe download from:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148
Example of use:

C:\PortQryV2>PortQry.exe -n 127.0.0.1 -e 3306

Querying target system called:

127.0.0.1

Attempting to resolve IP address to a name...

IP address resolved to WF-SA02

querying...

TCP port 3306 (unknown service): LISTENING

C:\PortQryV2>

Comment: A simple `telnet port` would do it, to see if there's anything running at that port. That will print an error if there's a MySQL server (since the protocols differ) but at least you can verify that a server is running.

Answer (score 0):

Might be an SSL problem. The problem is: XAMPP does not use SSL and MySQL Workbench uses SSL as a default setting.
You can select "If available" in the Use SSL dropdown box of the SSL tab of the connection pane. 
Use the tool icon in the startup window to edit already existing connections. 
Works in MySQL Workbench 8.0.28+